# Create and Delete Extensions for Asterisk via Python

Tags: python, asterisk, freepbx

I have a python script that needs to add new Extensions for users when they get to a certain point in my app. Not sure what libraries to use as pyst and another library don't work at all for me I cant get them to import.

I really just need to be able to create a new Extension with unique user and pass and pass along that information to the user so they can login on the softphone. I also need to be able to delete specific Extensions as needed when they are no longer needed.

Still fairly new to Asterisk(FreePBX) and can't figure out how to do this on AMI or ARI by itself not including using a python api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you "just need add extension" - use asterisk REALTIME architecture with mysql database and put info into db.

However most systems also need control extension dialplan. How to do that you can read, for example, in Freepbx.org source code.